# Multiple download content in UITableView (with ProgressView bar)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiprogressview

TableView that displays a number of downloadable content. When I click it on a button within the cell the download starts. I can download one file at a time (file that I received is good). But, if I download more than one at a time, the files that I received all are mixing up. How can I change this code to be able to download more than one file at once.

Here is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}
RPlayList * tanRPlayList = (dloadList)[indexPath.row];
rowID = tanRPlayList.xid;

cell.textLabel.text = tanRPlayList.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = tanRPlayList.khname;                  
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:tanRPlayList.stationImage];

// remove any previous buttons or progress bars from this cell
for (UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIProgressView class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
// look for active connecton for this cell
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self getConnectionInfoForRow:indexPath.row];

if (dict) {
    // there is an active download for this cell, show a progress bar

    UIProgressView *dlProgress = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];

    dlProgress.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-60, 10, 50, 9);

    dlProgress.tag = indexPath.row; // * 10 + 1;

    float fNumber;

    fNumber = (float)[[dict objectForKey:@"receivedBytes"]intValue] / (float)[[dict objectForKey:@"totalFileSize"]intValue];

    dlProgress.progress = fNumber;
    if((int)fNumber == 1){
        dlProgress.hidden = YES;
    }
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dlProgress];

} else {
    UIButton *dl = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    dl.tag = indexPath.row; // * 10;
    [dl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btndownload_06.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    dl.frame = CGRectMake(215, 10, 100, 30);
    [dl addTarget:self action:@selector(btnDLoadSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dl];
}
return cell;}


- (void)btnDLoadSelected:(UIButton*)sender{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    int selected_index = btn.tag;
    RPlayList * tanRPlayList = (dloadList)[selected_index];
    NSString *cellValueRowID = tanRPlayList.xid;
    NSString *cellValueName = tanRPlayList.name;
    NSString *cellValueKHName = tanRPlayList.khname;
    NSString *cellValuePLink = tanRPlayList.plink;
    NSString *kSort = tanRPlayList.sort;
    NSString *iconName = tanRPlayList.stationImage;
    [btn setHidden:YES];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:cellValuePLink];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:120];
    NSURLConnection *con=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    //  then create dictionary
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:con forKey:@"connection"];  // save connection so we can reference later
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag] forKey:@"row"];  // this is the row index from your table
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:999] forKey:@"totalFileSize"];  // dummy size, we will update when we know more
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"receivedBytes"];

    NSString *fileName = [cellValuePLink lastPathComponent];
    DLOAD_PATH = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",DLOAD_PATH0,fileName];
    [self.activeConnections addObject:dict];
    if(con){
        myWebData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    NSString *stationName = [cellValueName substringToIndex:3];
    [appDelegate.mKhemaDB beginTransaction];
    //NSLog(@"I am at End btnDLoadSelected ...");
}

- (NSMutableDictionary*)getConnectionInfo:(NSURLConnection*)connection{
    for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in self.activeConnections) {
        if ([dict objectForKey:@"connection"] == connection) {
            return dict;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary*)getConnectionInfoForRow:(int)row{
    for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in self.activeConnections) {
        if ([[dict objectForKey:@"row"] intValue] == row) {
            return dict;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self getConnectionInfo:connection];
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:response.expectedContentLength] forKey:@"totalFileSize"];
    [myWebData setLength: 0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self getConnectionInfo:connection];

    //NSNumber bytes = [data length] + [[dict objectForKey:@"receivedBytes"] intValue];
    NSInteger bytes = [data length] + [[dict objectForKey:@"receivedBytes"] intValue];

    //[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:response.expectedContentLength] forKey:@"receivedBytes"];

    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:bytes] forKey:@"receivedBytes"];


    int row = [[dict objectForKey:@"row"] intValue];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    [self.aTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [myWebData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    //Write file to folder
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self getConnectionInfo:connection];

    [self.activeConnections removeObject:dict];

    [myWebData writeToFile:DLOAD_PATH atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"Finished DLoaded File!");
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [aDloadList count];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIButton *b = nil;
    for(UIView *v in cell.subviews) {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            b = (UIButton*)v;
            break;
        }
    }
    b.tag = indexPath.row;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. Just add to dictionary:

```
NSMutableData *myWebData1 = (NSMutableData *)[dict objectForKey:@"myMutData"];

[myWebData1 appendData:data];



   - (void)btnDLoadSelected:(UIButton*)sender{

    //.....

//  then create dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:con forKey:@"connection"];  // save connection so we can reference later
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag] forKey:@"row"];  // this is the row index from your table
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:999] forKey:@"totalFileSize"];  // dummy size, we will update when we know more
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"receivedBytes"];

[dict setObject:[NSMutableData alloc] forKey:@"myMutData"];
[self.activeConnections addObject:dict];

if(con){
    myWebData = [[NSMutableData data]initWithLength:0];
}
}
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

    // ...

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self getConnectionInfo:connection];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:response.expectedContentLength] forKey:@"totalFileSize"];


myWebData = [[NSMutableData data]initWithLength:0];
[dict setObject:[NSMutableData alloc] forKey:@"myMutData"];}


    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {


    // ...

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self getConnectionInfo:connection];

NSInteger bytes = [data length] + [[dict objectForKey:@"receivedBytes"] intValue];

[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:bytes] forKey:@"receivedBytes"];

if(!myWebData)
    myWebData = [NSMutableData data];


NSMutableData *myWebData1 = (NSMutableData *)[dict objectForKey:@"myMutData"];

[myWebData1 appendData:data];


    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    // ...

//Write file to folder
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self getConnectionInfo:connection];

[self.activeConnections removeObject:dict];

NSData *myData1 = [dict objectForKey:@"myMutData"];

[myData1 writeToFile:DLOAD_PATH atomically:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ASINetworkQueue. It will allow you to create a queue of ASIHTTPRequests that can still be started asynchronously. For example :

```
- (void)getImages
{
    if(!self.queue)
        self.queue = [[[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init] autorelease];

    NSArray* urlStringsToRequest = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.example.com/image1.png",@"http://www.example.com/image2.png",nil];
    for(NSString* urlString in urlStringsToRequest)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
        [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
        [self.queue addOperation:request];
    }

    [self.queue go];
}

- (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest*)req
{
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[req responseData]];

    [imageArray addObject:image];
}

- (void)requestWentWrong:(ASIHTTPRequest*)req
{
    NSLog(@"Request returned an error %@",[req error]);
}
```

Thanks,